# problems with babel react preset and react-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm using webpack and babel to pre-process my jsx files to javascript. My configuration looks like this:

**Webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./react/main.jsx",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./public/javascripts/app.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**./react.main.jsx**

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import HelloWorld from './components/helloworld.jsx'
render(<HelloWorld />,document.body);
```

**./react/components/helloworld.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    static render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                <p>This is some text</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

When I run webpack I keep getting the error `React is not defined` at this line in app.js

```
(0, _reactDom.render)(React.createElement(_helloworld2.default, null), document.body);
```

If I specifically include react in my main.jsx file that error goes away and then the error is

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.` pointing to the `null` value as the second parameter of `React.create element` in app.js

I'm sure it's something I'm missing or doing wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Did you have react installed in you node_modules folder ? ( npm install -save react )

Comment: You should use document.getElementById('root') for example and have     <div id="root"></div> in your html file. You should not have the error  Target container is not a DOM if you do that

Comment: of course you also need to importing `React` in your *main.jsx*.  `react-dom` uses `react` too

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code into your ***main.jsx*** file.

```
import React from 'react'
```

as a `react-dom` uses `react`, but the primary reason is that the file contains JSX and JSX is just converted to React.createElement calls - *Felix Kling*

*From upgrade Guide React v0.14*

> Passing document.body directly as the container to ReactDOM.render now
>   gives a warning as doing so can cause problems with browser extensions
>   that modify the DOM.

So change your markup to

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

After that you can render your component to the *div* tag

```
render(<HelloWorld />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to explain why that's needed, so that others understand the issue.

Comment: *"as a react-dom uses react."* That's probably also an issue, but the primary reason is that the file contains JSX and JSX is just converted to `React.createElement` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I didn't realize that `react-dom` didn't `require 'react'` on its own.  at any rate, the other half of the issue was the placement of app.js after it was compiled. I put it at the bottom after the body and everything worked perfectly. I did get a warning about `document.body` so I'll change that to use a div instead.

Comment: You don't have to import React because of ReactDOM. You have to import React because you are using JSX, which just gets translated to `React.createElement` calls.